# Is it possible to make developer options inaccessible via tapping build number 7 times?

Tags: settings, developer-options

I want the developer options can only be accessed through a shell, please explain how to do it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve from this? Is your phone accessed by an another person and you want them to prevent them accessing those settings? Is your phone rooted and which  phone and Android version are you using? An Xposed module can easily hide a settings entry.

Comment: for security reason, my brother sometimes mess up with it, it isn't rooted and the version is 5.1, can you explain how to do it with Xposed module?

Comment: Why don't you setup a separate user account for your brother? As for Xposed module, it is pretty easy to use. See https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wilco375.settingseditorpro

Answer (score 1):

To disable developer options:

1. Go to Settings and scroll all the way down to Developer Options.
2. If you manage to identify a button (toggle) next to Developer Options, go ahead and tap it. All the options inside the tab will be grayed out, meaning they are disabled.
3. Open the Settings menu of your Android device.
4. Scroll down and tap on Apps (Applications). On Samsung, you need to go to Apps > Settings > Applications > Application manager.
5. Make sure you have the ALL apps filter selected.
6. Scroll down and tap on the Settings app.
7. Tap on Storage and hit Clear data and confirm by tapping Delete.
8. Go back to the Settings menu and check to see if Developer options is gone. If it’s still present, restart your phone and check again.

[image: Clear data for the settings app]